# Special character in rdlc filtering

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I have this problem in filtering special character in rdlc but when I am using this code in datagridview it running with out error.

```
    Me.StockcardMaterialTableAdapter.Fill( Me.aldrichDataSet28.StockcardMaterial)
    
    Dim Tarantado As New ReportParameter("GAGO", YY.Value)

    Try
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
            Dim keyword As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
            StockcardMaterialBindingSource.Filter =
     "(ProductName  LIKE '%" & keyword & "%')"


            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {Tarantado})
            ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()


        ElseIf TextBox1.text = Nothing Then

            StockcardMaterialBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
            ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString(),
      "Error Handler - Code A Minute.",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Finally
        TextBox1.Focus()

    End Try
    txtmonth.Text = ""
    txtTin.Text = ""
    txtQuarter.Text = ""
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2RyK.png)

Comment: You didn't ask any question or post any error. Post error messages as *text*, not images. Images can't be googled or compiled. On Windows you can use `Ctrl+C` to copy the contents of a Message box

Comment: I suspect the real problem is concatenating user input to construct a SQL query with  `"(ProductName  LIKE '%" & keyword & "&')"`. This can easily lead to SQL injection attacks or conversion errors if the input contains a single quote like `'`. Imagine what would happen if someone entered `'; drop table users;--`.

Comment: SSRS (RDLC is the client component of SQL Server Reporting Services) allows you to specify report and query parameters. There's no reason to concatenate user input to construct queries

Comment: I have this problem in filtering special character in rdlc but when I am using this code in datagridview it running with out error.